# Using PostSharp Logging for tracing

Tags: c#, postsharp

I am new to PostSharp and haven't use it before. I google long time but did not find any beginners start with the details. All the tutorial I found just exploring an example (crating new class which inherits from `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` and using it).

Did not find any initial steps. So as usual I add the PosSharp using NuGet(right click on project->manage nuget package). It seems like trial. not sure.

the secon question I am having is is there any way to log these to a text file as Log4net.

Please direct me to the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a tutorial on how to add tracing to your project with PostSharp, then there is one available in documentation: http://doc.postsharp.net/content/logging

It's also recommended to install PostSharp Visual Studio extension from the VS Gallery, if you didn't do so already. It will provide you with smart tags and wizards to perform most common tasks. The extension is availalable at this URL: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a058d5d3-e654-43f8-a308-c3bdfdd0be4a